# Java XOR Neural Network not training properly

Tags: java, neural-network, xor

I have a neural network with 2 inputs, 2 hidden neurons and 1 output neuron to solve the `xor` problem. I randomly initialise the weights between 0 and 1, I use a learning rate of `0.1` with `sigmoid` activation function.

When I train only one option, for example 1 and 0 with a target of 1, it works fine and gives an appropriate guess. However, when I try and train all the possible inputs together, the output converges around `0.5-0.6`.

I have tried changing the learning rate, the range that the weights are randomly initialised and the number of times the network is trained, however it makes no difference to the final output.

Here is a link to my code on [GitHub](https://github.com/Conor-Behard333/NeuralNetwork/tree/master/src).

Any ideas on how I could fix this issue?

Comment: maybe you can look at the following to get a clue: https://medium.com/@jayeshbahire/the-xor-problem-in-neural-networks-50006411840b.
Just one hint. like in this document and in general its a good idea to visualize results of trying different methods.

Comment: What I struggle to understand is why it works perfectly fine when I train just one option but when I train them all collectively it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the backpropagation isn't implemented properly. An overview is given in e.g. http://users.pja.edu.pl/~msyd/wyk-nai/multiLayerNN-en.pdf in particular pages 17 to 20.

The `tuneWeigths`- and the `delta_weights`-method of the `Output_Neuron`-class are implemented properly. However, in this step the array `weightDeltaHidden` (see comment in the code) must be determined that will be needed later when the weights of the `Hidden_Neuron`-class are tuned.

The `tuneWeigths`- and the `delta_weights`-method of the `Hidden_Neuron`-class don't seem to be implemented properly. Here, among other things, the previously determined array `weightDeltaHidden` must be used.

In the code below I've made the necessary changes without essentially changing the design of the code. But maybe a refactoring makes sense.

Changes in the `Output_Neuron`-class:

```
...

private double[] weightedDeltaHidden;

...

Output_Neuron(int hiddenNeurons) {

    ...

    this.weightedDeltaHidden = new double[hiddenNeurons];
}

...

void tuneWeights(double LR, double[] hidden_output, int target) {
    double delta = (target - output) * f.dSigmoid(output);
    for (int i = 0; i < weights.length; i++) {
        weights[i] += delta_weights(i, LR, delta, hidden_output);
    }
}

double delta_weights(int i, double LR, double delta, double[] hidden_output) {
    weightedDeltaHidden[i] = delta * weights[i]; // weightedDeltaHidden is the product of delta of this output neuron and the weight of the i-th hidden neuron.
                                                 // That value is needed when the weights of the hidden neurons are tuned...
    return LR * delta * hidden_output[i];
}

...

double[] getWeightedDeltaHidden() {
    return weightedDeltaHidden;
}
```

Changes in `Hidden_Neuron`-class:

```
...

void tuneWeights(double LR, int[] inputs, double weightedDeltaHiddenTotal) {
    for (int i = 0; i < weights.length; i++) {
        weights[i] += delta_weights(LR, inputs[i], weightedDeltaHiddenTotal);
    }
}

private double delta_weights(double LR, double input, double weightedDeltaHiddenTotal) {
    double deltaOutput = f.dSigmoid(output) * weightedDeltaHiddenTotal;
    return LR * deltaOutput * input;
}

...
```

Changes in the `Network`-class inside the `train`-method where the tuning of the hidden weights takes place:

```
void train(int[] inputs, int target) {

    ...

    //tune Hidden weights
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfHiddenNeurons; i++) {
        double weightedDeltaHiddenTotal = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < numOfOutputNeurons; j++) {
            weightedDeltaHiddenTotal += output_neurons[j].getWeightedDeltaHidden()[i]; // weightedDeltaHiddenTotal is the sum of the weightedDeltaHidden over all output neurons. Each weightedDeltaHidden
        }                                                                              // is the product of delta of the j-th output neuron and the weight of the i-th hidden neuron.
        hidden_neurons[i].tuneWeights(LR, inputs, weightedDeltaHiddenTotal);
    }
}
```

With those changes, a typical output for 1_000_000 `train`-calls (2 hidden neurons) is

```
Error: 1.9212e-01 in cycle 0
Error: 8.9284e-03 in cycle 100000
Error: 1.5049e-03 in cycle 200000
Error: 4.7214e-03 in cycle 300000
Error: 4.4727e-03 in cycle 400000
Error: 2.1179e-03 in cycle 500000
Error: 2.9165e-04 in cycle 600000
Error: 2.0655e-03 in cycle 700000
Error: 1.5381e-03 in cycle 800000
Error: 1.0440e-03 in cycle 900000
0 0: 0.0170
1 0: 0.9616
0 1: 0.9612
1 1: 0.0597
```

and for 100_000_000 `train`-calls (2 hidden neurons)

```
Error: 2.4755e-01 in cycle 0
Error: 2.7771e-04 in cycle 5000000
Error: 6.8378e-06 in cycle 10000000
Error: 5.4317e-05 in cycle 15000000
Error: 6.8956e-05 in cycle 20000000
Error: 2.1072e-06 in cycle 25000000
Error: 2.6281e-05 in cycle 30000000
Error: 2.1630e-05 in cycle 35000000
Error: 1.1546e-06 in cycle 40000000
Error: 1.7690e-05 in cycle 45000000
Error: 8.6837e-07 in cycle 50000000
Error: 1.3603e-05 in cycle 55000000
Error: 1.2905e-05 in cycle 60000000
Error: 2.1657e-05 in cycle 65000000
Error: 1.1594e-05 in cycle 70000000
Error: 1.9191e-05 in cycle 75000000
Error: 1.7273e-05 in cycle 80000000
Error: 9.1364e-06 in cycle 85000000
Error: 1.5221e-05 in cycle 90000000
Error: 1.4501e-05 in cycle 95000000
0 0: 0.0008
1 0: 0.9961
0 1: 0.9961
1 1: 0.0053
```

An increase of the hidden neurons increases the performance. Below a typical output for 1_000_000 `train`-calls (4 hidden neurons) is shown:

```
Error: 1.2617e-02 in cycle 0
Error: 7.9950e-04 in cycle 100000
Error: 4.2567e-04 in cycle 200000
Error: 1.7279e-04 in cycle 300000
Error: 1.2246e-04 in cycle 400000
Error: 1.0456e-04 in cycle 500000
Error: 6.9140e-05 in cycle 600000
Error: 6.8698e-05 in cycle 700000
Error: 5.1640e-05 in cycle 800000
Error: 4.4534e-05 in cycle 900000
0 0: 0.0092
1 0: 0.9905
0 1: 0.9912
1 1: 0.0089
```